# how to get the column mismatch report when i have two dataframes in which second dataframe has more column than first one

Tags: r

I have two data frames:

```
a1 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b=letters[1:5], c=c('a','t','f','e','v'))
a2 <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b=letters[1:3])
```

which i want to compare and want to get the number of column mismatch in both dataframe.

```
comparison <- compare(a2,a1,allowAll=TRUE)
```

Comment: what is the expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

use the dplyr method given below :-

```
require(dplyr) 
new <- anti_join(a1,a2)
```

Answer (score 0):

To just get the number of missing columns:

```
length(c(setdiff(names(a1), names(a2)), setdiff(names(a2), names(a1))))
[1] 1
```

To get the names:

```
c(setdiff(names(a1), names(a2)), setdiff(names(a2), names(a1)))
[1] "c"
```

Answer (score 0):

The column mismatch report, this will give you the list of the column that is not available in the second database

```
setdiff(colnames(a1),colnames(a2))
```